# MySQL pre-made functions

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a small class of pre-made MySQL functions (for example a function 'insert()') where some params are passed and an insert is executed. This allows me to develop faster.

I was wondering if there is something done already, such as CodeIgniter's one, but just a class that I can just include, without having to use a whole framework. Preferably PDO, PHP5, any really good one that you can recommend? I've been googling for a while but can't find anything useful.

Comment: In other words, you're looking for ORM? There's plenty of them, [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) and [Propel](http://www.propelorm.org/) are probably most well-known.

Comment: You should be able to grab individual classes related to DB operation from a framework of your choice, without having to use the entire framework. Just google `PHP ORM` or `PHP Database abstraction` and you should get plenty to choose from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest I have seen is [NotORM](http://www.notorm.com/). I guess you can't get any easier than this:

```
include "NotORM.php";
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=software");
$db = new NotORM($pdo);
```

You can use [this tutorial](http://phpmaster.com/database-interaction-made-easy-with-notorm/) to learn more.